# SQL Server 2008 Update Trigger not working when any changes in specified column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a below trigger in sql server 2008, its not triggering whenever the changes happened in my W_Data table column PLName. I am seeing the same column count in A_Ticket. Could anyone please help me?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_W_Data
    ON dbo.W_Data
    after update
    AS
        declare @date datetime

        select @date = max(Start_Date) from dbo.W_Schedule

        set NOCOUNT ON;

        if update(PLName)

    begin
      update t set
        I_S1_O = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
        I_S1_R = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
        I_S1_Re = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
        .....
      from ATicket t
    end
    go
```

Comment: This is because of your conditions. What do you mean by if update(plname)?

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz any update happen in PLName column in W_Data this should execute the update query

Comment: You're not referencing any of the pseudo tables `Inserted` or `Updated` in your trigger - so you're not really looking at the rows that have been updated ......

Comment: @marc_s what is the solution for this ?

Comment: You need to read up on trigger and how to reference those pseudo tables to get the rows that have been updated, and do something with them! [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) on Technet is a great start

Comment: @marc_s I have understand how the trigger will work. If i am correct What i need is something like this IF exists(select PLName
             from deleted i join W_Data m
             on i.ID = m.ID and i.PLName = m.PLName)

Comment: You need to be aware that the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will contain **multiple rows** - you cannot just do a `SELECT .. FROM Inserted` - you need to **JOIN** those pseudo tables against your base tables to do whatever you want to do in your trigger. **DO NOT** assume that there's only one row in those tables - there will be cases when there are multiple rows!

Comment: @marc_s Thats why i am joining the ID and PLName. As you said ID and PLName will have multiple rows. So what else i can join? pls advise... or give me some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, in a trigger, you should always reference the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables. For an `UPDATE` statement, `Deleted` will contain the old values (before the update) while `Inserted` will contain the new values.

You should then join those pseudo tables which tell you which rows have been updated against your own data tables to do something to those data tables - or to write audit records to another table - or something - whatever it is you want to do.

But be aware: the trigger will **not** fire once per row and contain a single row in `Inserted` - it will fire **once per statement** and thus more often than not contain **multiple rows** of data being updated.

So basically, your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_W_Data
ON dbo.W_Data
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  DECLARE @date DATETIME

  SELECT @date = MAX(Start_Date) FROM dbo.W_Schedule

  UPDATE t
  SET 
     I_S1_O = (select count(*) from dbo.W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
     I_S1_R = (select count(*) from dbo.W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
     I_S1_Re = (select count(*) from dbo.W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
        .....
   FROM dbo.ATicket t
   INNER JOIN Inserted i ON ....(whatever JOIN condition makes sense).....
   INNER JOIN Deleted d ON  ....(whatever JOIN condition makes sense).....
   WHERE
       d.PLName <> i.PLName  -- take those rows where the "PLName" column has been updated
```

Comment: i have modified the same but when i update the table it is completing and showing (1 row(s) affected) (7 row(s) affected). But the count not updated in A_ticket. Could you pls advise when the trigger will fire for my case. Sorry for asking silly questions.

Comment: @Sathish: the trigger will fire every time you **update** your `dbo.W_Data` table.